# Good Pattern for executing SELECT after INSERT with Amazon Aurora Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

Imagine you have an Amazon Aurora Postgres DB.  You perform an INSERT into one table.  You then need do a SELECT to get the auto-generated `CompanyId` of the newly added record.  You determine that there is often a significant enough delay between when the INSERT occurs and when the record is available to run the SELECT on.

I've discussed with my colleagues some possible code patterns to best handle this lag time.  What, in your opinion, is the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a separate SELECT statement. The best and most efficient option is to just use the `returning` clause:

```
insert into some_table (c1, c2, c3) 
values (...) 
returning *;
```

Instead of `returning *` you can also specify the column you want, e.g.: `returning company_id`

---

Another other option is to use `currval()` or `lastval()` after the insert to the get the value of the sequence directly:

```
insert into some_table (..) 
values (...);

select lastval();
```

The usage of `lastval()` requires that no other value is generated by a different sequence between the INSERT and the SELECT. If you can't guarantee that, use `currval()` and specify the name of the sequence:

```
insert into some_table (...) 
values (...);

select currval('some_table_company_id_seq');
```

If you want to avoid hardcoding the sequence name, use [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE)

```
select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('some_table', 'company_id'));
```